# Why is json becoming invalid while sending from browser to node js server

Tags: node.js, json, string, mongodb, express

I have an application that has a dashboard where you can edit certain infastructur in the app when the user preses update the browser collects the data and uses JSON.stringify to send it to the node js server via fetch but and on the server i try parsing the json with jsonlint but I get this error

### Error: Parse error on line 1:
... zum ändern":"Arzt",,"Zugriff zum sehen"

Expecting 'STRING', got ','

but this should be impossible thats the data the browser stringifed and the node js is trying to prse it

```
//this is the fetch function
async function postJSON(method, url, body, json, admin) {
  const data = {
    ...body,
    session_id,
    s_id: admin ? undefined : station._id,
  };
  const raw = JSON.stringify(data);
  //condole.log is logging valid json according to jsonlint
  console.log(raw);

  try {
    const res = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/" + url, {
      method,
      headers: {
        accept: "application/json",
      },
      body: raw,
    });

    return json ? await res.json() : await res.text();
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error:", error);
  }
}

//this is the server side resiving function
const jsonlint = require("jsonlint");
   module.exports = function (req, json) {
     let buffer = [];
     return new Promise((resolve) => {
       req.on("data", (data) => {
          buffer.push(data);
       });
    req.on("end", () => {
      const data = buffer.toString();
      console.log(data.substring(0, 10));
      jsonlint.parse(data);

     if (json) resolve(JSON.parse(data));
     else resolve(data);
        });
    });
};
```

Comment: I can't make out what it is exactly your trying to do but there is a value missing between those two commas `,,`. It is likely that you are pushing to an array or object and on that iteration the value being pushed was empty.

Comment: @jQueeny json.stringify makes empty values into null and my problem is that after sending the json data to the server it seems unvalid althoung previously it was valid (in the browser)

Comment: Thank you for explaining, I see your problem now.

Comment: Have you done any debugging? Have you checked what `buffer` is? It isn't a `Buffer` object, it's an array of `Buffer` objects. `.toString()` on an array, most of the time, doesn't make a valid JSON string.

Comment: And why aren't you using the builtin JSON middleware to read JSON?

Comment: @gre_gor the issue was that with the previous way of resiving the data some of it was lost now with Buffer.concat(buffer).toString() its fixed I dont use the built in express json parser because I didnt know it existed until yesterday

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const data = buffer.toString();
```

this is the problem it seems using buffer.toString() is causing data to diappaer

instead use:

```
const data = Buffer.concat(buffer).tostring();
```